# Text drawn by grid.text is not placed at the right location in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose we have the following faceted plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ cyl)
```

[image]

If we would like to include the text 'center' at the exact center of the plot, we may call to `grid.locator()`, click at the center of the plot and store the location of our mouse click using a specified coordinate system.

```
crds <- grid.locator(unit = 'npc') # click in the center of the plot
> crds
$x
[1] 0.534709193245779npc

$y
[1] 0.643171806167401npc
```

We can now use these coordinates in a call to `grid.text()` to place the text at the very center of the plot.

```
grid.text(
  label = 'center',
  x = unit(crds$x, 'npc'),
  y = unit(crds$y, 'npc'),
  gp = gpar(fontsize = 11, fontface = 2)
)
```

The printed text appears at the right x coordinate, but the y coordinate seems to deviate about 15% from the expected location.

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?